# Erroneous code, when overriding async method. Can this behavior be turned off?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, async-await

Let's consider this class:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual async Task FooAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

If you'll try to override `FooAsync` by typing "override" + selecting `FooAsync` from list, VS 2013 code editor will generate this code:

```
    public override async Task FooAsync()
    {
        return base.FooAsync();
    }
```

which, obviously, won't compile, until you'll change `return` to `await`.

I know, that `async` is an implementation detail, and it could be changed in derived type, but this isn't a cause to generated code, which doesn't compile initially.

Can this behavior be turned off (e.g., using some VS settings)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thanks. Can you turn your comment into answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't *believe* that there's a way to change this behaviour. The code to be added comes from a snippet, found (on my machine) under `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\vc#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodOverrideStub.snippet`. The snippet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Method Override Stub</Title>
            <Description>Snippet for overriding a method</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Refactoring</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>signature</ID>
                    <Default>signature</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>CallBase</ID>
                    <Function>CallBase(method)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[$signature$
{
    $end$ $CallBase$
}]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Unfortunately, as you can hopefully see, the actual "interesting" bits that determine the method signature and invoke the base class method are not part of the snippet - they're calculated by code instead.

Visual Studio 2015 (looking at RC / 14.0.22823.1 D14REL) appears to resolve the issue, but in the opposite way to how you've asked - it avoids copying `async` into the signature, which is more correct since `async` really *shouldn't* be considered as part of a method signature, as I think you yourself allude to in your question; It's an *implementation* detail and changing how the method is implemented shouldn't affect the signature.